# Render to vector file using command line + Freestyle

Tags: python, command-line, freestyle, vector

I am trying to render to a vector file using Freestyle. I have enabled it in my file and when I render to image via GUI, it generates both a PNG and an SVG file, so everything is OK. When I do it via command line (using the same file), it only generates the PNG file. This is the command that I'm using:

```
 --background x.blend --python blender_script.py -E BLENDER_EEVEE -o C:\\tmp\vector.svg -f 0
```

In blender_script.py I'm only changing the line weight.

How can I get the SVG file via command line (or editing the python script)

Thanks!

**EDIT: It started working with this exact command line after I restarted Blender (maybe then it saved the settings related to Freestyle when I closed it?)**

Comment: What exactly `blender_script.py` is doing?

Comment: It only changes the line thickness like this `scene.render.line_thickness = 20.0`

Comment: Set the extension to any supported image format like `-o C:\\tmp\vector.png` and the svg file comes along if *freestyle svg addon* is enabled.

Comment: It started working with the exact command line that I was using after I restarted Blender (maybe it saved the settings related to Freestyle when I closed it?)

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by this comment, the only thing I can say is that it's working (I did test it) when using an extension that is regonized by blender @Marc

Comment: Yes, it's working. But I had Blender open, in the same session where I installed the freestyle plugin and set all settings. At that time it was only working from the GUI. When I closed blender and executed the same command again, it started working from the command-line too.

Comment: Not related to this. When calling blender via command line a new instance of blender will be created anyway. I guess the addon wasn't enabled at this time @Marc